# A statement of double integral which is closely related to Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, weierstrass-approximation

we know that due to the Weierstrass approximation theorem. if we have a nonnegative function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and f is continuous and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$, **then** we will have $f=0$ on $[a,b].$

Now I have a slightly different one. Suppose we have a non-negative continous function $f(x,y)$ defined on $[a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}
$ and we have $\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dy=1$, for all $x \in [a,b].$ Can I prove that $f(x,y)$ is just a function of $y$ on $[c, d]$?

Obvious the non-negativity is important, otherwise I can choose $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{3}{2}y^2$ and $[c,d]=[-1,1].$
Then $\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dy=1$. But $f(x,y)$ is not just a function of $y$.
Can somebody help me with this? What I think is that we can use a similar approach to the Weierstrass approximation theorem. But I can not figure out how to do it.
If we add more condition (like $f(x,y)$ is $C^{\infty}$). It seems like it didn't help.

Comment: Think about functions of the form $f(x,y) = g(y-x)$.

Comment: Actually you do not need Weierstrass approximation to prove that assertion.

Answer (score 1):

$[a,b]=[-\frac1  2, \frac 1 2], [c,d]=[-1,1]$ and $f(x,y)=\frac 1 2+xy$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Nice example